# Sort mysqli from a many-to-many table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm trying to make a internal web based message system, with a *amp system, primarily for learning purposes. I don't know if this is a trivial topic, but   I'm having difficulties so please bear with me.

The goal is to list all the contacts ordered by the last message sent / received.
Currently without sorting it the SQL looks like this

```
$query = "SELECT username, user.id as user_id,  

(SELECT COUNT(message_read)  
FROM message_user  
WHERE message_read = 0 
AND sent_id = user_id  
AND receive_id = {$userId}) as unread  

FROM user  
WHERE user.id IN  
(SELECT contact_id FROM allowed_contact WHERE user_id = {$userId})   
;";
```

The structure of the tables are:
The `user` table has an `id`,
That links to the `message_user` table which has a `sent_id` and a `receive_id`,
The `message_user` has a `message_id` that corresponds to the `message.id`,
The `message` table has a `timestamp`.

I would like this to be done in SQL but if it comes down to PHP I resign to resort to that.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: The `$userId` is the auto-generated id created by mysql that came from the database. This value is not provided by the user.

Comment: You say that and yet I'd bet money somewhere in your code is `$userId=$_GET['userId']`. Don't take chances.

Answer (score 1):

This works.

```
SELECT `u`.`id` AS user_id, username,
(SELECT COUNT(message_user.message_read)  
FROM message_user  
WHERE message_user.message_read = 0 
AND sent_id = user_id  
AND receive_id = {$userId}) as unread  

FROM `user` AS `u`
LEFT JOIN `message_user` AS `mu` 
ON 
    (CASE WHEN `u`.`id` != {$userId}
        THEN `u`.`id` = `mu`.`sent_id`
        WHEN `mu`.`sent_id` = {$userId} AND `mu`.`receive_id` = {$userId}
        THEN `u`.`id` = `mu`.`sent_id`
    END)
OR  
    (CASE WHEN `u`.`id` != {$userId}
        THEN `u`.`id` = `mu`.`receive_id`
    END)

LEFT JOIN `message` AS `m` ON `m`.`id` = `mu`.`message_id`

WHERE u.id IN  
(SELECT contact_id FROM allowed_contact WHERE user_id = {$userId})
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY MAX(`m`.`timestamp`) DESC;
```

[This](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/sql-select-distinct-and-order-by/) broke down the problem I was having.

@Andreas thanks for time and help.

Comment: That does seem overly complicated but that's made necessary by the unusual schema you've employed. I think you could adjust your tables to make this sort of query easier. Don't forget to test something like this at scale, load in tens of thousands or millions of dummy messages if necessary, to be sure you're indexing things properly.

Comment: Now that you're asking me to take look at the schema, I could put a timestamp on `message_user`. It would still be almost as complex, but by removing the second `LEFT JOIN` it improve performance. I could justify it by saying if a message is sent twice it should be seen by the time received, not the time created. I guess I get too involved in the details and forget to look at the total picture, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 `LEFT JOIN` with a `DISTINCT` (untested):

```
SELECT DISTINCT `u`.`id`
FROM `user` AS `u`
LEFT JOIN `message_user` AS `mu` ON `u`.`id` = `mu`.`sent_id` OR `u`.`id` = `mu`.`receive_id`
LEFT JOIN `message` AS `m` ON `m`.`id` = `mu`.`message_id`
ORDER BY `m`.`timestamp` DESC;
```

Comment: It still doesn't order it properly, when I add the `timestamp` to the `SELECT DISTINCT` it gives it in order but with duplicities.